# Doing a join/lookup in JPA - Java Spring boot

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I need to do a table look up in my database using JPA annotations.

Just want to say -- the extended table isn't managed on my side -- so it comes from an imported third party source -- so the user will register and their data/login will be processed on accounts.... the lookup will be a one to one on their pin to the extended table to gain access to the extra data - if it exists.

I've only used JPA for 1 day so - could really do with some support/help on gaining access to a 2nd table in this fashion.

So lets say in accounts

```
id | username | password | email        | pin
1  | Lucy     |  1234    | lucy@gm.com  |  4321
```

and in extended

```
id | gender  | dateofbirth  | personpin
4  |  f      |  15/01/1990  |  4321
```

---

I want to do a look up or a join -- to fetch the data - based on the "pin"

```
id: 1,
username: Lucy
password: 1234
email : lucy@gm.com
pin : 4321
gender : f
dateofbirth: 15/01/1990
```

I have two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "error.username.null")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 12, message = "error.username.minlength")
    private String username;

    @NotNull(message = "error.password.null")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 12, message = "error.password.minlength")
    private String password;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "error.email.null")
    @Size(min = 7, max = 128, message = "error.email.minlength")
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "error.pin.null")
    @Size(min = 4, max = 8, message = "error.pin.minlength")
    private String pin;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String userName) {
        this.username = userName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public String getPin() {
        return this.pin;
    }

}
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Extended")
public class Extended {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "error.personpin.null")
    @Size(min = 4, max = 8, message = "error.personpin.minlength")
    private String personpin;

    @NotNull(message = "error.gender.null")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2, message = "error.gender.minlength")
    private String gender;

    @NotNull(message = "error.dateofbirth.null")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 128, message = "error.dateofbirth.minlength")
    private String dateofbirth;

    public Extended(){

    }

    public Extended(String personpin, String gender, String dateofbirth) {
        this.personpin= personpin;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;     
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    public void setPersonPin(String personpin) {
        this.personpin = personpin;
    }

    public String getPersonPin() {
        return this.personpin;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateofbirth) {
        this.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return this.dateofbirth;
    }

}
```

I have seen methods of doing a ManyToOne - but where do I do this -- in the accounts entity? Or in the repo? I will have a third table - which is populated from a set of forms the users will fill in, once logged, so I will need to add more joins/queries to see how many forms they have done -- what's the next increment -- results from these forms.

so it will be something like getExtendedData(user.pin), getFormData(user.id)

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="account_full",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(pin = "pin", 
                              referencedColumnName = "pin"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(personpin = "personpin", 
                              referencedColumnName = "personpin"))
Group group;
```

[image]

Comment: You need to study database design and normalization. You shouldn't store the same information in two different tables. And you should use the primary key (id) instead of a functional column (pin) to refer to the account from "extended". I also don't understand why all the information in extended is not stored in account directly. A person doesn't have many genders, nor many dates of birth. Those 3 tables should be a single one.

Comment: -- the extended table won't be managed on our side -- the data will come from a third-party source. It will be a one to one relationship - so I ask again -- using JPA -- how would you perform a lookup account.pin to extended.personpin

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql.

Comment: Thank you for the documents - do you feel you could put it as an actual answer relating to the entities I have. Like I say -- I am not doing a look up on id's but different cols -- and its not a phone book application. I have yet to be paid for this project and already doing design,ux and frontend work, to now read through another source on JPA - I do have access to google - I am seeking an actual technical answer show casing why and how this solution should be implemented.

Comment: I'm not going to do your job, especially after you've basically admitted you didn't want to learn, but only to have a ready-to-copy-and-paste solution. And especially since I completely disagree with your design..

Comment: Its not that I don't want to learn - I don't understand how to implement the required examples you've given in my exact example. I've asked for a technical answer here so as to learn how this done.. I was taught not to write the queries like that -- but to use a repo

Comment: I've got a repo to access the tables like this -- 
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
 Account findByUsername(String username) throws Exception;
 List<Account> findByEmail(String email) throws Exception;
 Account findByPin(String pin) throws Exception;
}